# How to click Button webbrowser delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

```
<div id="lowbtn">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="start" a2s="click" obj="MAIN_START" opt="{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;L_Start&quot;}"><img src="http://test/btn.png" alt="Go!" class="loading" data-was-processed="true"></a>
            <ul class="server" style="display: none;">
                <li class="Talk">
                    <span class="icon"><img src="http://test/assets/common/btn/icon.png" alt="" class="loading" data-was-processed="true"></span>
                    voice
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="on" id="a_voice_check"><span class="hide">on</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

my delphi code

```
procedure TMainForm.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
var
  CurrentBrowser: IWebBrowser2;
  TopBrowser: IWebBrowser2;
  Document: OleVariant;
  Doc3 :  IHTMLDocument3;    
begin
  CurrentBrowser := pDisp as IWebBrowser2;
 TopBrowser := (ASender as TWebbrowser).DefaultInterface;
 if Assigned(CurrentBrowser) and Assigned(TopBrowser) then
  begin
   if CurrentBrowser = TopBrowser then
    begin

   doc3 := (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Document as IHTMLDocument3;

   doc3.getElementById('lowbtn').click;     


  end;


  end;
```

I've tried different methods, but AV is occurring or doesn't work. Does anyone know a problem with my code or know a solution?

thx..

Comment: On which line is the AV occurring? Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: According to my experience, the DocumentComplete event is frequently triggered before the document and all dependencies have been downloaded. To verify this, put your code behing a TButton that you'll click when you see the document is really complete, or use a TTimer to defer the code for long time enough (just for testing, don't do that in production).

Comment: What strikes me sporadically: div-Element id="lowbtn" has no Click.

Instructions can be found at:
https://github.com/delphidabbler/articles/blob/master/article-22-pt1.pdf to
https://github.com/delphidabbler/articles/blob/master/article-22-pt6.pdf